# Can I change the default of "block-size" in commands?

Tags: command-line, disk-usage, ls

Several commands use --block-size 1K as the default and I find myself counting numbers. Is there a way to automatically and permanently change the block-size of commands like du,ls,df to greater values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All those commands you mentioned (`du`, `df`, `ls`) have a `-h` option to make the output sizes "human-readable", using K, M, G and T as appropriate.

If you want to avoid adding the 'h' everytime, simply define bash aliases that include it, eg

```
alias duh='du -h'
alias lsh='ls -h --color -F '
```